# Android Webviews and internal querystrings

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm using Android, and I've created a Webview which nicely opens my HTML page (page "A").

Now, I want to follow some links I have on page "A", which go to page "B".

If I click on a linkl defined with 
`<a href="page_b.html">` everything is fine, and the Webview behaves just like a normal browser, goinmg to the selected page.

But if I click a link defined as `<a href="page_b.html?param=x">` all I get is a "Web page not found".

The same if I use an anchor like `<a href="page_b.html#2">`.

How can I pass parameters between different HTML pages within the same Webview?

---

### EDIT:

Nevermind, I managed to pass the parameter I needed using localStorage.

Of course, after a gazillion dry runs, I discovered I had to enable it in the WebView with settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true) :D

Comment: <a href=page_b.html?param=x"> a quote is missing should be <a href="page_b.html?param=x">, can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Yes, of course... mistyped it here, but doesn't work anyway in a Webview :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I discovered I had to set `settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)` in the WebView, and the easiest solution for my problem I found was:

In "Page A.html", I intercept the onClick event of the links, and use localStorage to store the id:

```
$(".link").each(
    function()
    {
        divId=+$(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+divId).click(function(e)
        {
            localStorage.my_id=divId;
        });
    });
```

In "Page B.html", I retrieve the stored id:

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    divId=localStorage.my_id;
    isReady();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem, try this:

```
   this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

...

```
    vw = new MyWebView(this);
    vw.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(title);
        }
    })
```

;